# Android url.openStream slow?

Tags: android

Im using the following code to retrieve some text from a http-server. The size is less than 1 kB and is generated in 0.002 milliseconds

However, retreiving the data may take 600 ms, but mostly between 2000 and 5000 ms.

the following code is used:

```
long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      StringBuffer SB = new StringBuffer();
      Common.toLog("101 took "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) + " ms");
      try {
          URL url = new URL(Common.server+request);
          Common.toLog("102 took "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) + " ms");
          InputStreamReader ISR = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
          Common.toLog("102a took "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) + " ms");
          BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(ISR);
          Common.toLog("103 took "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) + " ms");
          String inputLine;
          while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
              SB.append(inputLine);
          }

          in.close();
          Common.toLog("105 took "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime) + " ms");
      } catch (IOException e)
      {
          Common.toLog("Could not make connection 1");
          showMSG(R.string.ERROR_NO_INTERNET, true);
      }
```

The most timeconsuming method is between log-point 102 and point 102a. When using chrome i can load [the page](http://home.peterelzinga.eu/phpjsinterface/browse.php?action=getCPL) within 300-350 ms. I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to retrieve this data

Answer (score 0):

The data you're pulling back isn't really that long.   Instead of opening a read stream to the URL, try using one of the implementations of HttpRequest:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html

This way, a single request is made and your data would come back in the response.  For example, you could try an HttpGet request:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// Execute HTTP Get Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
content = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: It is better than before, using the following script:
http://androidforums.com/application-development/9261-doing-http-request-android.html However: the responce time for the first request still takes 1600 ms, against +/- 700 seconds for the next request